# Can't capture strings in the "select" of "where (select..."

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to select a string value based on a sub-query that returns another string value.

While cases like

```
select * from ForgeRock where (SELECT count(*) from...) = 1;
select * from ForgeRock where (SELECT num1 from...) = num2;
```

work, something like this returns 0 lines:

```
select * from ForgeRock where (SELECT name from...) = 'OpenDJ';
```

**Please note**: I'm talking about cases where

```
SELECT name from...
SELECT num1 from...
```

return exactly 1 row. The following don't help either:

```
select * from ForgeRock where (SELECT min(name) from...) = 'OpenDJ';
select * from ForgeRock where (SELECT top 1 name from...) = 'OpenDJ';
```

Here is a fiddle link that demonstrates the problem with strings:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7540/1711

Here is another fiddle link that proves there's no problem with numbers:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a7540/1715

So...how can I manage to grab those sub-query strings?

Comment: To me it looks like you are trying to do something the wrong way. perhaps if you share your actuall problem (I mean, the thing that makes you think that this kind of sql is a good solution) someone will be able to come up with a simpler, working solution. a golden rule in programming is that sometimes all you need a s fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: Hey @ZoharPeled, it's a bit complicated.  
When using queries in Excel, it only allows dynamic values and not dynamic field names. For example, you can tell it **"select where name = ?"** and **"?"** would be taken from cell a1. But you can't do **"select where ? = 'something'**.  
I decided to bypass that limitation by using:  

    select * from foobar where (select name from sys.columns where object_id = object_id(N'foobar') and name = ?) like '%'+?+'%'
  
But then I ran across the aforementioned problem...

Comment: @ZoharPeled, I moved my comment to you into [its own thread](http://superuser.com/questions/905841/dynamic-field-names-in-excel-queries).

Comment: It is hard to figure out what you want to achieve. Don't compare Excel with SQL. Excel is a tool made for users. SQL is a language you use in combination with a programming language or a reporting tool, to give your users a tool. And a program that needs to acces system tables is very rare. The only one I can think of is a database administration tool. So what are you trying to do?

Comment: Your fiddles, by the way, don't match. Replace 3 from your number fiddle with 'productName' and you will see that the string works just like the number. In your string fiddle you sometimes use 'productName' and sometimes 'OpenDJ'. You could just as well replace a 3 with a 4 in your number fiddle and complain that you suddenly don't get no matches any longer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this:

```
(SELECT 'productName') = 'OpenDJ'
```

it does the same as:

```
'productName' = 'OpenDJ'
```

That will never be true.

This will give you a result:

```
select * from ForgeRock where productName = (select 'OpenDJ');
```

Comment: Yup. Looking at the fiddle, you basically have a select with a false where clause which will return nothing.

Comment: So how do I remove the single quotes from the select's result? I want productName = 'OpenDJ' and not 'productName' = 'OpenDJ'

Comment: @LWC: You want to use a value as a field name? You can't do that. The only way to use names dynamically is to create the query dynamically, i.e. create the entire query as a string and execute it.

Comment: @Guffa, are you talking about Excel? Is it possible without VBA?

Comment: @LWC: It's not possible using SQL, any dialect.